# handling exceptions for Http rest endpoints in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I need to throw an exception to the end user, can you please assist with this?

```
<int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <!--<bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
                    <property name="recoveryCallback">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                            <constructor-arg ref="retryErrorChannel" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryLoadTemplate" />
                </bean>-->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                    <property name="successChannel" ref="afterSuccessFetchChannel" />
                    <property name="failureChannel" ref="afterFailFetchChannel" />
                </bean>
            </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
        <int:transformer ref="testTransformer" method="processDetails" />

<int:transformer input-channel="afterSuccessFetchChannel" output-channel="goodResultChannel"
                     expression="'Fetching load id: ' + payload + ' details was successful'" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="afterFailFetchChannel" output-channel="badResultChannel"
                     expression="payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + payload.cause.message" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="badResultChannel" level="ERROR"/>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="goodResultChannel" level="INFO" />
```

How and where to handle custom exceptions and how to re throw them?

My api is throwing 404 Not found exception, need to catch and re throw it to the user?
for now, I am just using logging channel, I don't really know the way to deal with exceptions in spring integration, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of that `<int:logging-channel-adapter id="badResultChannel" level="ERROR"/>` you just need to write some POJO method which would throw some other exception after its handling. The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` has this property `returnFailureExpressionResult` to be set to `true`.

The logic is like this:

```
    try {
        evalResult = this.onFailureExpression.getValue(prepareEvaluationContextToUse(exception), message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        evalResult = e;
        logger.error("Failure expression evaluation failed for " + message + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

and then:

```
        if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
            Object evalResult = evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
            if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                return evalResult;
            }
        }
```

So, your custom thrown exception is going to be sent as a reply message payload back to the caller. And there probably an MVC layer can simply convert it to respective HTTP response for the client.

Comment: thanks! can you please direct me to some code sample where exception is handled as above?

Comment: I would move your `payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + payload.cause.message` to the `onFailureExpression` option of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. The `<int:transformer input-channel="afterFailFetchChannel"` better to call some service method to re-throw a custom exception based on a result of that expression evaluation. The `cause.message` better to take from the `#exception` SpEL variable since the `payload` is going to be from a request message, not an `ErrorMessage` as you expect now.

Comment: do you have some example for it? sorry, little confusing for me! #exception is available on the expression?

Comment: Some example is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/intermediate/retry-and-more. It might not answer to all your questions, but at least some start. So, for me it would be like this: `<property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message" />`. This one is going to be a `String` of the payload you will receive in the `afterFailFetchChannel`. Your POJO method for that transformer could just `throw new` for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.expression.Expression' for property 'onFailureExpression': no matching editors or conversion strategy found, but it already is a string! <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message" />

Comment: Right. Sorry, see an `onFailureExpressionString` instead.